# get the values of a specific line from a specific column

Tags: linux, bash, cut

what I want is to extract the list of a table with the following format

```
+---------+---------------+-------------+
| Region  | Parent Region | Description |
+---------+---------------+-------------+
| region1 | None          |             |
| region2 | None          |             |
+---------+---------------+-------------+
```

From region I want to get region1, region2.

what I have tried so far is

```
$ cat file |cut -d'+' -f1|cut -d'|' -f2

 Region  

 region1
```

Any idea?

sed command which returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if `sed` is the right tool for this instead a native DB tool, but here you go:

```
sed -nE '3,$ s/^\|[[:blank:]]*([^[:blank:]|]*).*/\1/p' file.txt
```

- `3,$` does the operation only from line 3 till end
- `^\|[[:blank:]]*([^[:blank:]|]*).*` matches `|` at the start and then whitespaces (if any) and the captured group contains the desired portion
- In the replacement we have used the first (only) captured group, `\1`

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt
+---------+---------------+-------------+
| Region  | Parent Region | Description |
+---------+---------------+-------------+
| region1 | None          |             |
| region2 | None          |             |
+---------+---------------+-------------+

$ sed -nE '3,$ s/^\|[[:blank:]]*([^[:blank:]|]*).*/\1/p' file.txt
region1
region2
```